# Confusing CRON job answer from Microsoft

Tags: azure, cron

This is the question from Microsoft AZ-204 practice paper:

> You create a batch routine by using a timer trigger in Azure Functions. You need to configure the batch routine to execute every 15 minutes. Which code segment should you use?

As you can see in the screenshot below, the suggested answer is **0 */15 * * * 1-5**

From the best of my knowledge, the second field in CRON format is hours, so it makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain?

[image]

Comment: It means - Every hour, at second:00 and then every 15 minutes beginning at minute:00 according to this Cron generator here- https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions does not use regular UNIX cron expression.

> Azure Functions uses the NCronTab library to interpret NCRONTAB expressions. An NCRONTAB expression is similar to a CRON expression except that it includes an additional sixth field at the beginning to use for time precision in seconds:
>
> {second} {minute} {hour} {day} {month} {day-of-week}

Also:

> NCRONTAB expression supports both five field and six field format. The sixth field position is a value for seconds which is placed at the beginning of the expression.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#ncrontab-expressions

Comment: Somehow I never came across NCRONTAB expressions, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize that there were six fields in the expression so I didn't suspect.